# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

src/Service/Post.js

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query"
    
    export const postAPi=createApi({
        reducerPath:'postApi',
        baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({
            baseUrl:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
        }),
        endpoints:(builder)=>({
            getAllPost:builder.query({
                query:()=>({
                    url:'posts',
                    method:'GET'
                })
            })
        })
    })
    export const { useGetAllPostQuery }=postAPi
```

src/App.js

```
import { useGetAllPostQuery } from './Service/Post'

export default function App() {
  const data=useGetAllPostQuery()
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>
          React App
        </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I fetch data using RTK query so,when I try to access useGetAllPostQuery in my app.js react component then it saw me error in browser
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function so, anyone can suggest how to solve this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not importing the `query/react` endpoint. The normal `query` endpoint does not create hooks.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react"
```

Comment: thank you sir , I import wrong , now it's working

Comment: I used VS code auto import and it's imported from

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati importing from `@reduxjs/toolkit/query` is perfectly fine **if you do not use React and do not want the hooks**. If you use React, you need to use `@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react`. Only you as a human can decide that, your auto-import cannot make that decision.

Answer (score 0):

A typo can cause the error too.
Be careful of the auto-generated hooks.

```
export const { use_____Query } = ~~APi
```